# DateTime in Calendar Extender

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am using calendarextender control in asp.net.It displays only date ,not time.But while inserting to database ,time is inserted automatically.But while retrieving the data from database using date in where condition ,no correponding records displays.What modification in storedprocedure i can do to resolve this problem.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of code from your stored procedure of your date query in the where clause?

Comment: Can you also provide details on the version of database you are using

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are most likely encountering is that if you are looking for a date equal to 3/11/2009 you'll probably never find it, because of the time stamp.  A few methods you could use to change the strored procedure would be to consider the range for the date:

Using the Between Statement will give you an inclusive range

```
Select myname,mydate from sometable 
    where mydate between 3/10/2009 and 3/11/2009
```

Or

Using > and < to give you an exclusive range

```
Select myname,mydate from sometable 
    where mydate >3/10/2009 and mydate < 3/12/2009
```

Or

Leverage the DateAdd function to strip the time off the field. There are some good examples of this at the [SQLTeam Blog](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/01/02/56079.aspx)

```
dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,myDate))
```

Or
If you can change the Table itself and you are using SQL Server 2008 you could use the new SQL Server 2008 **Date** DataType, a date with no time component to deal with.  There's a good blog over on MSDN blogs about the new [Date and Time enhancements in SQL Server 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/manisblog/archive/2007/08/28/sql-server-2008-enhancements-in-date-and-time-data-types.aspx).

Don't forget you could also look into the insert procedure(if applicable) and zero out the time.

Also when dealing with datetime make sure to factor in **>= and <=**  so you don't miss any records.

Hope this gives you enough options to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

in database datetime datatype includes both date and time regaredless wheather you supply only date or date time . if you insert date as '1/1/2011' then it will be interpreted as 
1/1/2011 00:00:00 AM

which in select query fails because it tries to compare both date and time (for instance between same dates ie. 'between 1/1/2011 and 1/1/2011'

use either day/month/year component like clause or use <,> operator
ie

```
select thisone from sometable where day(tabledate) between day(wheredate1) and day(wheredate2)
  and month(tabledate) between month(wheredate1) and year(wheredate2)
and year(tabledate)  between year(wheredate1) and year(wheredate2)
```

or

```
select thisone from sometable where tabledate>=wheredate1 and tabledate<=wheredate1
```

the operator = applies on case wheather you use inclusive or exclusive search